# Uploading multiple files in PHP using HTML Form or cURL

Tags: php, curl, file-upload

I was uploading a file using multipart/form-data, and getting the uploaded file in another php file to use it somewhere else.

This was the multipart/form-data I was using:

```
<html>
<body>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="facebook.php" method="post">
    <p><label for="source">Photo</label><input type="file" name="source" /></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Upload" /></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Now I changed to use cURL to upload the file, because I wanted to upload more the one file, so i needed to not use the form.

This is the code I am using now:

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init('http://localhost/faceads/facebook.php');
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
        'files[]' => '@C:\xampp\htdocs\faceads\Assento-Novo.png',
    ),
));
if (false === ($res = curl_exec($ch))) {
    die("Upload failed: " . curl_error($ch));
}
?>
```

I am trying to get the uploaded file in facebook.php in the same way I was doing before, but it is not working, and because I know almost nothing about cURL I don't know how to do it.

This is the facebook.php file now:

```
if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    $uploaddir = './uploads/'; // Upload folder
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['source']['name']);
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['source']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
       USE THE FILE URL
               .
               .
               .
    }    
}
```

Anyone can help me saying how can I get the uploaded file using cURL?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't need cURL to upload multiple files; you can upload a bunch of them just using a regular form.

### Uploading multiple files using HTML Form

Client-Side

```
<!-- uploader.html -->
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="uploader.php">
    <input name="blob[]" type="file" /><br />
    <input name="blob[]" type="file" /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload these files" />
</form>
```

Server-Side

```
// uploader.php
if(isset($_FILES["blob"])){
    for($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES["blob"]["name"]); $i++){
        $tmp_name = $_FILES["blob"]["tmp_name"][$i];
        $blob_name = "file-name.ext"; // generate an unique name
        if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "destination-folder/" . $blob_name)){
        // do something with the uploaded file
        }
    }
}
```

### Uploading multiple files using cURL

```
$request = curl_init('http://domain.com/uploader.php');
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt(
    $request,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
    array(
        'blob[0]' => '@' . realpath('first-file.jpg'),
        'blob[1]' => '@' . realpath('second-file.jpg')
    )
));
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
echo curl_exec($request);
curl_close($request);
//
// for the other part use the uploader.php code from above
```

Comment: The problem is that I want to it without the necessity to fill the form manually, thats why I am using cURL.

My question here is how I get the results from the cURL. How can I get the uploaded file in the facebook.php

Comment: Well, make a file, let's say curl.php, then use the snippet from the above, make another file and name it uploader.php or facebook.php, use the other snippet I sent in my answer and that's it. Be sure to use the right path for the files and check if you have a permission to write on that uploading folder.

Comment: My ploblem is: I don't know what to write in the uploader.php/facebook.php to use the uploader file, like I did when I was using the form.

Comment: You just have it from my answer. Otherwise, you may use the same file you used before.

Comment: In my file, I had the uploaded file URL in the $uploadfile variable do I can use it later. In your answer, using the cURL, where can I find it? Thanks

Comment: Fix it. I was really confused about how to use cURL, but now I understood how it works, i was thinking that I have to substitute the form for it, and not use both of them together. Thanks for your help and sorry for my idiot questions!