# How to upload file using curl under foreach

Tags: php, curl, post

i am trying to upload file using curl but if two file are trying to upload then its upload same file twise .

```
ch_thumb = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch_thumb, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch_thumb, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch_thumb, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$fname = $file_name;
$data->$fname = new CURLFile ('images/'.$fname);
curl_setopt($ch_thumb, CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD, true);
curl_setopt($ch_thumb, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$resp = curl_exec($ch_thumb);   
clearstatcache();                       
curl_close($ch_thumb);
```

please provide solution for that how can i solve.

Comment: This [SO Link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24397973/2679536) has a solution for multiple file upload using cURL.

Comment: i am able to upload file but same file was upload i send different file name but get previous file on both response

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uploading multiple files in PHP using HTML Form or cURL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24397621/uploading-multiple-files-in-php-using-html-form-or-curl)

Answer (score 0):

Just make a function and add this function into foreach loop like below u get it.

```
<?php
    foreach($url)
    {
    upload_file($url);
    }    
    function upload_file($url)
    {
      // Add your file upload code in this function 
    }
?>
```